# Show that $(\mathbb{R}^*, \cdot)$ is not cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm trying to prove that the group $(\mathbb{R}^*, \cdot)$ is not cyclic (similar to [1]). My efforts until now culminated into the following sentence:

> If $(\mathbb{R}^*,\cdot)$ is cyclic, then $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}^*$ such that $x \cdot x \neq x \in \mathbb{R}^*$.

The assumption written above is only not true for the neutral element on $\mathbb{R}^*$. Are there any follow-ups that I should do to improve that sentence?

[1] [Show that (Q, +) and (R, +) are not cyclic groups.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491510/show-that-q-and-r-are-not-cyclic-groups)

Comment: Do you mean *not* cyclic?

Comment: It's not. The subgroup $(0, \infty)$ of $\Bbb{R}^*$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb{R}, +)$, with $\ln$ being one such isomorphism.

Comment: yep, I know for a fact that it isn't cyclic, followed by the set of rational numbers not being cyclic.

Comment: Your statement is true for any non-trivial group. I don't understand what you think it has to do with cyclicity.

Comment: @Thorgott, I'm trying to get my head around the concept of cyclic groups. If I state that 1 is not a generator of the $\mathbb{R}^*$ group over $\cdot$, should this one statement invalidate the affirmation of the group $\mathbb{R}^*$ is cyclic?

Comment: Can you try to show by contradiction? Say there is a generator $a$ of the group then consider its inverse.

Comment: @ChitoMiranda for every generator $a$ of $\mathbb{R}^*$ I get, I also find an inverse of that generator.

Comment: The set $\mathbf R^\times$ is far too big:  prove a cyclic group is at most countable.

Comment: What can you say about the inverse $b:=a^{-1}$ of $a$ if $a$ generates $\mathbb{R}^*$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any $n \in \Bbb N, -1$ has no $n$th root in $\Bbb R^*$ except (when $n$ is odd) $-1$ itself.  Therefore, if $-1 \neq x \in \Bbb R^*, -1 \notin \langle x \rangle$.  Since $-1$ also does not generate  $\Bbb R^*, \Bbb R^*$ is not cyclic.

Comment: I don't follow why only when $n$ is odd. If $n$ is odd then it has the form of $2n-1$. $-1 =2n-1$ following that $n$ is zero.

Comment: I think I got it, $-1^n$ times. If $n$ is odd then the result is $-1$ itself.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $(\mathbb{R}^*, \cdot)$ is cyclic then there exist $x\in \mathbb{R}^*$ such that $\mathbb{R}^* = \langle x \rangle =\{x^n \vert \, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. However we see that the set  $\{x^n \vert \, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is [countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) but $\mathbb{R}^*$ is [uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set) which is a cotradiction.

A similar argument shows that $\mathbb{R}^*$ can not be generated by a finite number of elements , that is for any reals $x_i$ ($i =1,2,\ldots ,n$) we must have $\mathbb{R}^* \ne \langle x_1, x_2 , \ldots , x_n \rangle$ for all positive integer $n$.

Comment: A similar argument shows that $\mathbb{R}^*$ cannot be generated by a *countable* number of elements, as there are countably many finite lists of natural numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $(\mathbb{R}^*,\cdot)$ is cylclic. Now $\langle2,3\rangle$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}^*,\cdot)$, but it is cyclic since it is a subgroup of a cyclic group and therefore $\langle2,3\rangle=\langle a\rangle$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}^*$. Now $a^n=2$ and $a^m=3$ for some $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$, which imples
$$a^{nm}=2^n=3^m$$
But $2$ and $3$ are prime and it is a contradiction.

Comment: This demonstration is quite clear to someone who hasn't seen isomorphism between groups.

Comment: Yes,
also we can use the fact that all cyclic groups are countable to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $G$ is a cyclic group and $H\cong G$, then $H$ is also cyclic. Now use the fact that $(\Bbb R, +)$ is not cyclic.

Also, every group satisfies $x^2\neq x$ for each $x\neq e$. Indeed, if $x^2=x$, then $x^2=ex$, so, multiplying by $x^{-1}$ on the right, we get $x=e$.

Comment: ≅ here means congruency, right?

Comment: No, @ranu; "$H\cong G$" means "$H$ is *isomorphic to* $G$".